# How to start appium servie via python coding and than run pytest script

Tags: python, appium, python-appium

I tried 
from `appium.webdriver.appium_service` 
`import AppiumService` and

```
appAppium = AppiumService()

appAppium.start()
```

but code throws an error in windows env.

> _____________________ ERROR at setup of TestLogin.test_C8275_Verify_User_Can_Enter_Valid_Password _____________________

```
self = <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x03B34A30>

def _new_conn(self):
    """ Establish a socket connection and set nodelay settings on it.

    :return: New socket connection.
    """
    extra_kw = {}
    if self.source_address:
        extra_kw['source_address'] = self.source_address

    if self.socket_options:
        extra_kw['socket_options'] = self.socket_options

    try:
        conn = connection.create_connection(
           (self.host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
```

> d:\python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py:141:
>
> ---

```
address = ('127.0.0.1', 4723), timeout = <object object at 0x00734BA0>, source_address = None
socket_options = [(6, 1, 1)]

def create_connection(address, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT,
                      source_address=None, socket_options=None):
    """Connect to *address* and return the socket object.

    Convenience function.  Connect to *address* (a 2-tuple ``(host,
    port)``) and return the socket object.  Passing the optional
    *timeout* parameter will set the timeout on the socket instance
    before attempting to connect.  If no *timeout* is supplied, the
    global default timeout setting returned by :func:`getdefaulttimeout`
    is used.  If *source_address* is set it must be a tuple of (host, port)
    for the socket to bind as a source address before making the connection.
    An host of '' or port 0 tells the OS to use the default.
    """

    host, port = address
    if host.startswith('['):
        host = host.strip('[]')
    err = None

    # Using the value from allowed_gai_family() in the context of getaddrinfo lets
    # us select whether to work with IPv4 DNS records, IPv6 records, or both.
    # The original create_connection function always returns all records.
    family = allowed_gai_family()

    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, socket.SOCK_STREAM):
        af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res
        sock = None
        try:
            sock = socket.socket(af, socktype, proto)

            # If provided, set socket level options before connecting.
            _set_socket_options(sock, socket_options)

            if timeout is not socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT:
                sock.settimeout(timeout)
            if source_address:
                sock.bind(source_address)
            sock.connect(sa)
            return sock

        except socket.error as e:
            err = e
            if sock is not None:
                sock.close()
                sock = None

    if err is not None:
       raise err
```

> d:\python\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py:83:

And if i use `os.call("appium")`
code hang after appium start.

I expect to have appium run in the background and my python android script sun after appium started.

Comment: Can you give us some additional code as context? Also the error you get would be helpful.

Comment: i added some part of my error in windows powershell.

Comment: i need to start appium programically via python language but lib provided by appium ddn't work.